# Initializing a C++ object / struct

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, constructor, default-constructor

What is the difference between the following initializations?

1. new MyClass()
2. MyClass()

From my understanding the first one allocates the memory on heap and returns a pointer whereas in the second case a reference to the object is returned but the object resides on stack. In both cases the default constructor is called. Please correct me if I am wrong.